# Null pointer exception on clicking the element in Appium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, appium, appium-android

**Please find the code written in the eclipse:**
Null pointer exception coming on the line in which the code for click on the element is written, please help me for this, I have invested so much time over this, it would be a great help if anyone will solve it.

```
public class StartApplication {

    private static AndroidDriver<WebElement> driver;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        File classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "/apps/Hooq/");
        File app = new File(appDir, "tv.hooq.android.apk");        
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "eeefe839");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0.1");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "tv.hooq.android");
        driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        driver.findElementById("tv.hooq.android:id/accountLogin").click();
    }
}
```

**Please find the exception from the console:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:279)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:83)
at StartApplication.main(StartApplication.java:29)
```

Comment: which line is 29?

Comment: Did you start the Appium server using command line? or using Appium Desktop? Which server arguments are you using?

Comment: @xinaiz driver.findElementById("tv.hooq.android:id/accountLogin").click();

Comment: @HassanRadi Using Appium Desktop, I am new to Appium so I am unaware of server arguments. please tell.

Comment: @AnubhavJain http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/server-args/

Comment: @HassanRadi If you are online then I can share my screen from team viewer, is it okay ??

Comment: I had a similar problem and i solved it by upgrading the appium dependency to version 5.0.1, although i am not sure wether its the latest one or not but the null pointer exception got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a splash screen of a app then just put implicit wait i.e driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

before findElementId. This happend just because of splash screen

Thanks

Comment: This is not an answer